Flutter long list quickly swipe up stuck
there. I have a 3000 items list in flutter app, although I use the ListView.builder function, but when I swipe up and down quickly, the list is not sliding up and down smoothly. My list item have Image, How to optimize them without adding list paging?
I try the cached_network_image and it have no obvious effect

Can you try increasing cacheExtent in listView

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
